# dealing with a variable of short data type

Tags: java

I am have a method in which the parameter I am receiving is "rowno" which is of type short.
The code is as shown below.

```
private int abcd (int a , short rownum)
{
    // method body
}
```

Now my query is this. Inside the method I have to perform some logic when the value of 
rownum is 5 , so I am trying like this

```
if (rowno == 5)
{
     //perform some operation

}
```

Please advise me whether this the correct approach for short type.

Comment: So what happened when you tried it?

Comment: no problem with the code. If you want to see more information about casting. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 3):

That should work fine.

When `rowno` is a `short`, the expression `rowno == 5` is equivalent to `((int) rowno) == 5` since Java implicitly promotes primitive operands.

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) says

> ## 5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion
>
> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 2 Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int**.
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> ...
>
> - The numerical equality operators `==` and `!=`

and the kind of conversion that happens here is safe according to

> ## 5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion
>
> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - ...
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - ...
>
> A widening primitive conversion from an integral type to another integral type, or from float to double in a strictfp expression (§15.4), does not lose any information at all; the numeric value is preserved exactly.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, 
Short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer.
and int data type us a 32-bit signed two's complement integer.

So when you do opration, the short data will auto cast to int data type without problem.
( No Widening Primitive Conversion needed -> no information lost)

Answer (score 0):

Don't see why that wouldn't work. If you really want to be sure you can always do this:

```
short compareValue = 5;

if(rownum == compareValue) {
    //logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your rownum parameter is something to do with database row id, or any number which could overflow range of short you could lost your integer information. if you are 101% sure that your input parameter value never gonna overflow of short range you are good to go.